# Convert drawing on canvas to icns

Tags: javascript, canvas, firefox-addon

Is it possible to convert a drawing on a canvas to `.icns` for Mac?

Anyone knows what icon format linux uses?

Comment: If there is no function for it you have to make it according to the its specification - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to my question for what icon type linux uses

I think linux uses png images for icons. Can someone please verify in comment.

### Solution to my question on how to convert to .icns

If anyone has any other ways please share, I love seeing multiple ways to do same and see the differences/quirks between them.

To convert to .icns in mac it was done on mxr here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/webapps/MacNativeApp.js#291

This is the code edited so it works outside of the scope from mxr above.

```
/**
* @param aIcon         nsIFile :: of icon
* @param aPath         String :: where you want to save the image and with what name
*/
_processIcon: function(aIcon, aPath) {
  let deferred = Promise.defer();

  //let tmpIconPath = OS.Path.join(aDir, this.iconFile);

  function conversionDone(aSubject, aTopic) {
    if (aTopic != "process-finished") {
      deferred.reject("Failure converting icon, exit code: " + aSubject.exitValue);
      return;
    }

    // SIPS silently fails to convert the icon, so we need to verify if the
    // icon was successfully converted.
    OS.File.exists(aPath).then((aExists) => {
      if (aExists) {
        deferred.resolve();
      } else {
        deferred.reject("Failure converting icon, unrecognized image format");
      }
    });
  }

  let process = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].
                createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
  let sipsFile = FileUtils.getFile("/usr/bin/sips");

  process.init(sipsFile);
  process.runAsync(["-s", "format", "icns",
                    aIcon.path,
                    "--out", aPath,
                    "-z", "128", "128"],
                    9, conversionDone);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

I haven't been able to test it as i dont have mac vm yet but hopefully it has no quality issues like I did on windows.